# Object posted through form is changed and its id is set to different one

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-core

When i post a form, vehicle id is set correctly but in my object named Order all properties are null and id is set to vehicle id. 
Sorry for my poor explanation but i'm not sure how to describe it.

Everything is fine when i debug GET method and view but when it comes to POST method and i hover my mouse above method parameters, `Order selected.id` is already the same as `int id`

Here's my code:

**View model:**

```
public class AssignOrderViewModel
{
    public Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }
    public List<Order> OrderList { get; set; }
    public Order SelectedOrder { get; set; }
}
```

**Order model:**

```
public class Order
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Address PickUpAddress { get; set; }
        public Address DropOffAddress { get; set; }
        public DateTime PickUpTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime DropOffTime { get; set; }
        public OrderState OrderState { get; set; }
        public List<Vehicle> AssignedVehicles { get; set; }
        public List<Cargo> Cargo { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller GET action:**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> AssignOrder(int? id, int? selectedOrderId)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var vehicle = await _context.Vehicles
                .Include(v => v.LoadingSpace)
                .Include(v => v.Position)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
            if (vehicle == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            var orderList = new List<Order>(_context.Orders.Include(o => o.PickUpAddress).Include(o => o.DropOffAddress).Include(o => o.Cargo).Include(o => o.AssignedVehicles).Include("Cargo.CargoUnit"));
            Order selectedOrder = null;
            if (selectedOrderId != null)
                selectedOrder = orderList.Where(o => o.Id == selectedOrderId).FirstOrDefault();

            AssignOrderViewModel assignOrderViewModel = new AssignOrderViewModel 
            { 
                Vehicle = vehicle, 
                OrderList = orderList, 
                SelectedOrder = selectedOrder
            };

            return View(assignOrderViewModel);
        }
```

**Controller POST action**:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("AssignOrder")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> OrderAssigned(int id, [Bind("Id,OrderState")] Order selected)
        {
            var vehicle = await _context.Vehicles.FindAsync(id);
            if (selected.OrderState == OrderState.NotAssigned)
            {
                var order = await _context.Orders.FindAsync(selected.Id);
                order.OrderState = OrderState.WaitingForPickUp;
            }
            vehicle.CurrentOrderId = selected.Id;
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
```

### AssignOrder.cshtml view

This one is quite big so i will try to show most important parts:

**Model:**

```
@model TransportationManagementSystem.Models.AssignOrderViewModel
```

**Selection of order:**
Its working properly, sends get and page is refreshed, selected order is highlighted.

```
@foreach (var order in Model.OrderList)
    {
            <a class="text-body order-element" asp-action="AssignOrder" asp-route-selectedOrderId="@order.Id">
                <div class="card my-3">
                    <div class="card-body order-element
                         @if (Model.SelectedOrder != null)
                         {
                         @(order.Id == Model.SelectedOrder.Id ? "selected-order" : "")
                         } ">
...
```

**Post form:** I think that its something wrong here.

```
    <form asp-action="AssignOrder">
                                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Vehicle.Id" />
                                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="SelectedOrder" />
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-2">Assign</button>
                                </form>
...
```

I tried removing input with `Vehicle.Id`, id was still set for vehicle and order id was still set as vehicle id.

I also tried: `<input [...] value="@Model.SelectedOrder" />` but it still didn't work.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: 1. how do you submit the form? Your above `<form>` is submitted by `GET` instead of `POST`.   2. Also, the field name is not correct. Please change them to `<input type='hidden' name="id" asp-for=''Vehicle.Id">` and `<input type="hidden" name='selected.Id' asp-for="SelectedOrder.Id" />  <input ...>`

Comment: I already gave up. Im just passing `int id` and `int selectedOrderId`. I think the problem was that both properties were named Id. Id in vehicle and id in SelectedOrder. I also had `method="post"`.